# Tableviews, cell editing and dragging

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a swift app with a tableview where the cells are dynamic. What I want to achieve is that the user can side swipe a cell and it brings up two tiles, one for editing and one for deleting (an example of this would be in the messages app where you side swipe for the delete option)

I have got the two tiles to show by using:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let editRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: " Edit ", handler:{action, indexpath in
    });
    moreRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexpath in

    return [editRowAction, deleteRowAction]
}
```

The first issue I have is how can I programatically close the side swipe when the edit option is selected so that the tiles are hidden and the user can see the textfield in the cell?

Second issue, when a cell is in edit mode I want to be able to move the cell in the tableview: following tutorials I have implemented the below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let sourceRow = sourceIndexPath.row;
    let destRow = destinationIndexPath.row;
    let object = ArrayList.objectAtIndex(sourceRow)
    ArrayList.removeObjectAtIndex(sourceRow)
    ArrayList.insertObject(object, atIndex: destRow)
}
```

and set the following when I want to put cell into moving mode

```
    TableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Which sort of does what I want, however when I put it into editing mode I get the delete icon on the left side of the cell (red circle with white dash) which I don't want, ideally I'd like my own icon so user can select and drag cell around but I feel this might be pushing it slightly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the remove button you should be able to set the editing style to none (or something else)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return tableView.editing ? UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None : UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
}
```

To hide to buttons after a swipe you can either set tableView.editing or reload the cell.

```
tableView.editing = false
```

alt

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

//All the involved delegate methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let editRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: " Edit ", handler:{action, indexpath in
            self.tableView.editing = false
    })

    let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexpath in
            self.tableView.editing = false
    })

    return [editRowAction, deleteRowAction]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return tableView.editing ? UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None : UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply, if i set func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
} it stops the tiles being shown completely

Comment: Can you toggle it on and off depending on which action you are performing?

Comment: what would i have to toggle it to for when i want the cells tiles visible? The ones i have tried don't seem to allow the tiles to be visible?

Comment: I updated the answer. I tried this version and it worked for me